# Hide columns that have column headers with no data?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to hide columns that have no data in it, while keeping the ones with data showing even if there is only one item in the column. Here is the code I'm using:

```
Dim cl as Range

For Each cl In Range("A2:U2")
    If cl.Value = "" Then
        cl.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        cl.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
Next cl
```

This works, however I do have it reading A2 to U2 and hides the columns, based on that row, including ones that do have information. Would I have to add something like xldown for it to read everything from that point to determine if it should hide the column? Much appreciated for the assistance!

Comment: Cycle through your columns and use `counta` or `countblank`

Comment: @findwindow I'm still learning all of this, how would I could about doing that?

Comment: You did `For Each cl In Range("A2:U2")` so I presume you know how to loop. Just do something like `if counta(col) >1` within the loop. Edit: research it and try it then come back with your updated code and I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Add a check for

```
If cl.end (xlDown).Row = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your `If` condition from

```
If cl.Value = "" Then
```

to

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(cl.Column).EntireColumn) = 1 Then
```

This tells you that there is only one value in the whole column. In your case it should be header.

It should look something like below:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim cl As Range

    For Each cl In Range("A2:U2")
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(cl.Column).EntireColumn) = 1 Then
            cl.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            cl.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for the response. I've used it and it isn't hiding any rows with no data. I'm guessing it's because it's reading the headers? I've tried modifying this so that it reads everything under the headers since there are columns that have no data and I don't need them, but still having a hard time.

Comment: @kjay - `If` condition is compared to `=1` to check that column only has header and no data. Its working for me with some test data. Is it possible for you to share your sheet so that I can look into it.

Comment: I can't actually since it's a work file. I have put it in break mode and have been seeing what's going on step by step.  When it gets to my column I, it does read that it is empty, however it goes straight to the false statement instead of true.

Comment: @kjay - Can you check the value of `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("I").EntireColumn)` in immdiate window.

Comment: Hi,
This has helped me a lot, and I am almost there with my macro! My situation is that before this macro is run, I filter most of the rows, and I want to run this macro only on the rows that are visbile.

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot!